# Visual Studio не находит метод Remove в Приложении ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, mvc, entity-framework

Уважаемые форумчане!

Почему-то не могу воспользоваться функциями для каскадного удаления данных из базы данных. Подключила к проекту Entity Framework, но это не помогло. По-прежнему, среда не знает функций **DbContext.Entities.Remove()** и **DbContext.SaveChanges()**. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Возможно, нужно ещё какие-то связи добавить в проект?

Вот код метода:

```
public void DeleteClientFromDb(int clientId)
{
   Client client = DBContext.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == clientId);
   DBContext.Clients.Remove(client);
   DBContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Код, где объявляется контекст базы данных:

```
public partial class CDBWrapper : IDBWrapper
{
   private ShopDBLinqDataContext DBContext;

   public CDBWrapper()
   {
       DBContext = new ShopDBLinqDataContext();
   }
}
```

Comment: покажите свой код

Comment: @ PashaPash, отредактировала вопрос и добавила код))

Comment: и еще тот кусок, где у вас DBContext объявлен

Comment: PS. покажите объявление DBContext.

Comment: @PashaPash, отредактировала, см. выше.

Comment: @ koks_rs, добавила код.

Comment: @cat_woman и еще объявление ShopDBLinqDataContext - все же интересно, какой у него базовый тип

Comment: А я правильно понимаю, что метод DeleteClientFromDb находится в классе CDBWrapper?

Comment: Можете показать класс `ShopDBLinqDataContext`?

Comment: @Vlad, а что там должно быть? Он огромный, с кучей методовй, автоматически генерируемых средой.

Comment: @ PashaPash, что это за базовый тип?

Comment: @cat_woman, интересует базовый тип, тип свойства Clients и наличие метода SaveChanges.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может быть в том, что в `EF` есть класс `DBContext`. Измените название вашей переменной, например, на `dataContext`:

```
public void DeleteClientFromDb(int clientId)
{
    Client client = dataContext.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == clientId);
    dataContext.Clients.Remove(client);
    dataContext.SaveChanges();
}

public partial class CDBWrapper : IDBWrapper
{
    private ShopDBLinqDataContext dataContext;

    public CDBWrapper()
    {
        dataContext = new ShopDBLinqDataContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы используйте неправильный подход.

**Рекомендации**

Экземпляр контекста не должен использоваться как обычный экземпляр класса, а должен существовать только во время связи (контакта) с БД. Для этого код, работающий с БД, должен находиться в теле `using`. Должно быть так

```
public void DeleteClientFromDb(int clientId)
{
    using(ShopDBLinqDataContext dataContext = new ShopDBLinqDataContext())
    {
        Client client = dataContext.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == clientId);
        dataContext.Clients.Remove(client);
        dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }    
}
```